# Как поместить массив байтов в qr code

Tags: java, qrcode, zxing

Необходимо большой текст поместить в qrcode. Текст сжимаю с помощью java.util.zip на выходе получаю byte[]. Qr код создаю библиотекой zxing, но он принимает только string строку.
Подскажите пожалуйста какие есть варианты решения?

Comment: А это вообще работает? Имею ввиду, что для разделения элементов массива байтов понадобиться разделитель и не увеличит ли это кодируемую информацию? В QR Code можно закодировать 7089 числовых знаков или 4296 буквенночисловых, что-же это за текст у Вас такой? P.S.: а какова величина компресии текста при его сравнении с текстовым представлением байтового массива?

Comment: Текст может быть различным. От одной страницы а4 и больше

Comment: Если библиотека работает только со `String`, то пробовали ли вы перевести byte array в String?

Comment: Создаётся впечатление, что Вы пытаетесь решить задачу/проблему нестандартными методами. QR Code не предназначен для таких задач. Может быть, если Вы опишите, что Вы пытаетесь сделать, то знающие люди подскажут.